# Bash script for file listing (html output)

Tags: html, bash, filelist

I've got a problem with writing small bash script for making html list of files based on names.
I've got files with a naming pattern INFO1 Bla Bla - INFO2 - INFO3.doc, and I want to have someting like this in a output:

```
<li id="INFO1Blabla">
<h5>INFO1 Bla bla</h5>
<p>INFO2</p>
<a href="files/INFO1 - INFO2 - INFO3.doc">download</a>
</li>
```

I'm trying to do this using bash + awk, but i've got some problems even when doing testing in a shell, as you see:

```
$ ls > list.txt
$ for i in 'cat list.txt'; do awk -F "-" '{print $2}' > list2.txt; done
```

And loop is probably infinitive, cause for 10min its working..

If somebody can help me, I'll be very happy cause I can't use php in this case and I need to generate this on my side using bash..

Cheers guys and take care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for f in *.doc; do ( 
    IFS=-
    set -- $f
    echo "<li><h5>$1</h5><p>$3</p><a href='files/$*'>download</a></li>"
)
done
```

The part in parentheses is executed in a subshell, so changes to IFS variable are localized. A test:

```
$ touch 'info1 - inf2 - info 3.doc'
$ touch 'First name blabla - Second part bla boa - third part, unimportant.doc'
$ for f in *.doc; do ( 
>     IFS=-
>     set -- $f
>     echo "<li><h5>$1</h5><p>$3</p><a href='files/$*'>download</a></li>"
> )
> done
<li><h5>First name blabla </h5><p> third part, unimportant.doc</p><a href='files/First name blabla - Second part bla boa - third part, unimportant.doc'>download</a></li>
<li><h5>info1 </h5><p> info 3.doc</p><a href='files/info1 - inf2 - info 3.doc'>download</a></li>
```

Comment: But I'm also wondering is it possible to give <li id=""> from $1 but without spaces, so when $1 is ONE TWO THREE, i want to have it as ONETWOTHREE, and without any special characts (like polish letters, cause I want to use it in jquery). Cheers

Comment: Sure, change `echo "<li>...` to `echo "<li id='${1// /}'>...`

Comment: but there are still polish letters in names, is it possible to convert them 'on the go' to all english, legit characters?

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for this?:

```
$ ls -1
INFO1 - INFO2 - INFO3.doc
INFO1 - INFO4 - INFO6.doc
l.sh

$ ./l.sh 
<li>
<h5>INFO1</h5>
<p>INFO2</p>
</li>
<li>
<h5>INFO1</h5>
<p>INFO4</p>
</li>
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.doc
do
    # split file-name into array
    IFS='- ' read -a array <<< "$i"
    echo "<li>"
    echo "<h5>${array[0]}</h5>"
    echo "<p>${array[1]}</p>"
    echo "</li>"
done
```

**update**

If filename looks like this:

```
First name blabla - Second part bla boa - third part, unimportant.doc
```

Change the IFS-parameter to a single `-` instead.

Make this change:

```
    IFS='-' read -a array <<< "$i"
```

output:

```
$ ./l.sh 
<li>
<h5>First name blabla </h5>
<p> Second part bla boa </p>
</li>
<li>
<h5>INFO1 </h5>
<p> INFO2 </p>
</li>
<li>
<h5>INFO1 </h5>
<p> INFO4 </p>
</li>
```

**update 2**

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.doc
do
    # split file-name into array
    IFS='-' read -a array <<< "$i"
    echo "<li>"
    echo "<h5>${array[0]}</h5>"
    echo "<p>${array[1]}</p>"
    echo "</li>"
    echo "<a href=\"files/${i}\">download</a>"
done
```

Output:

```
<li>
<h5>First name blabla </h5>
<p> Second part bla boa </p>
</li>
<a href="files/First name blabla - Second part bla boa - third part, unimportant.doc">download</a>
<li>
<h5>INFO1 </h5>
<p> INFO2 </p>
</li>
<a href="files/INFO1 - INFO2 - INFO3.doc">download</a>
<li>
<h5>INFO1 </h5>
<p> INFO4 </p>
</li>
<a href="files/INFO1 - INFO4 - INFO6.doc">download</a>
```

Comment: Great, glad I could help. Don't forget to upvote/accept when you have the rep to do so :-)

Comment: hey, but the problem is the files names are something like this:

Comment: hey, but the problem is the files names are something like this:
First name blabla - Second part bla boa - third part, unimportant.doc

So I need for ${array[0]} expression before '-' and after for ${array[1]}, is it possible that way?

Comment: See update. Hope that answers you question. If not, please update your question with valid input and expected output.

Comment: Man you are the best! I've got one more question, how to display as a last <a href="files/filename.doc">download</a>?

Comment: is the text static? if so, just add a line `echo "<a href="files/filename.doc">download</a>"` at the bottom

Comment: no no, the real filename with files/ at the beginning :) so for example, files/INFO1 - INFO2 - INFO3.doc

Comment: as I said, glad I could help :-) Keep them questions coming!